# Is there anyway to keep display block on the end of transition?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement staggering animation that should not affect another element's position near the target element. The transition is ok but the problem is when it is done animating, it sets `display: none;` property by default which makes the next element jumps up to fill it's position.

I was wondering if I could keep it `display: block;` and rely just on `opacity` instead but I can't get any clue from the docs. Is it possible? or should I use animation libraries instead?

To demonstrate, please run this snippet

```js
console.clear();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showItems: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.showItems = true
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.slide-in-enter-active {
  transition: opacity .5s linear, transform .5s cubic-bezier(.2, .5, .1, 1);
  transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * var(--i));
}

.slide-in-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .4s linear, transform .4s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .7, .4); //cubic-bezier(.7,0,.7,1); 
  transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * (var(--total) - var(--i)));
}

.slide-in-enter,
.slide-in-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-in-enter,
.slide-in-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(1rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="showItems = !showItems">Show/Hide Items</button>

  <!--
    in real world, this would be dynamic,
    which is the height is unknown (like larger text on a larger screen).
  -->
  <transition-group tag="ul" name="slide-in" :style="{ '--total': 10 }">
    <li v-for="i in 10" :key="i" :style="{'--i': i}" v-show="showItems">
      Item {{ i }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>

  <div class="the-content-that-should-not-moved-up">
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use visibility:hidden property instead of display:none

Comment: You want a big empty space where the items used to be when it's hidden?

Comment: @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan , this is what i'm askin about, how can i do that? the doc doesn't mention any property to set that.

Comment: @tony19, yes, it is ok to be a big empty space, i need the content below to stay at it's place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the current height of the list upon hiding it, and then apply a style binding to set its height accordingly:

1. Apply a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `transition-group` element (a `ul`) so that we could get the element's height later.

   ```html
   <transition-group ref="list">
   ```
2. Add a `listHeight` data property to store the `transition-group`'s height:

   ```js
   data() {
     return {
       listHeight: null
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a style binding to the `transition-group` element to set `height`:

   ```html
   <transition-group :style="{ height: listHeight && `${listHeight}px` }">
   ```
4. Add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `showItems` that captures the `transition-group`'s height only when hidden:

   ```js
   watch: {
     showItems(showItems) {
       if (showItems) {
         this.listHeight = null
       } else {
         this.listHeight = this.$refs.list.$el.offsetHeight
       }
     }
   }
   ```

```js
console.clear();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showItems: false,
      listHeight: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.showItems = true
    });
  },
  watch: {
    showItems(showItems) {
      if (showItems) {
        this.listHeight = null
      } else {
        this.listHeight = this.$refs.list.$el.offsetHeight
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.slide-in-enter-active {
  transition: opacity .5s linear, transform .5s cubic-bezier(.2, .5, .1, 1);
  transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * var(--i));
}

.slide-in-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .4s linear, transform .4s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .7, .4); //cubic-bezier(.7,0,.7,1); 
  transition-delay: calc( 0.1s * (var(--total) - var(--i)));
}

.slide-in-enter,
.slide-in-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-in-enter,
.slide-in-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(1rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button @click="showItems = !showItems">Show/Hide Items</button>

  <!--
    in real world, this would be dynamic,
    which is the height is unknown (like larger text on a larger screen).
  -->
  <transition-group tag="ul" name="slide-in" :style="{ '--total': 10, height: listHeight && `${listHeight}px` }" ref="list">
    <li v-for="i in 10" :key="i" :style="{'--i': i}" v-show="showItems">
      Item {{ i }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>

  <div class="the-content-that-should-not-moved-up">
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
    <p style="margin:0;">Another content that should not moved up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```